# nginx how to redirect aaa.com/app/query to ccc.com/#/query

Tags: nginx, redirect

My project requires configuring reverse proxy using Nginx. I want to proxy htttp://aaa.com/app/query to http://ccc.com/#/query.

I have tried several approaches, but none of them worked.

```
    location /app/query {
        set $target_uri '/#/query';
        rewrite ^/app/query.*$ $target_uri break;
        proxy_pass http://ccc.com;
    }
```

upstream acturally receive  '/%23/query'

```
    location /app/query {
        rewrite ^/app/query.*$ /#/query break;
        proxy_pass http://ccc.com;
    }
```

illegal config

```
    location /app/query {
        rewrite ^/app/query.*$ /%23/query break;
        proxy_pass http://ccc.com;
    }
```

upstream acturally receive  '/%2523/query'

upstream  expect recieve /#/query

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, the `#/query` part of the URL is not handled by ccc.com, it is handled by the browser. The [URL fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment) is not received by the server. The only way to redirect this query is by passing it back to the browser with `rewrite...redirect` - which will of course change the URL in the browser's address bar.

Comment: Thank you,It very useful for me @RichardSmith